# The socialengine widget content in the new created module is not get appear in the front end

Tags: php, zend-framework, widget, socialengine

I created a new module using the tutotorial https://jadb.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/social-engine-4-modules/

Its working as fine.

later i created a widget in the new module using the tutorial. https://jadb.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/socialengine-4-create-a-widget/

The widget folder was not created during the module creation time. so i created folder for widgets.
and also i added Controller.php and index.tpl files.

After i added the code mentioned in the tutorial to content.php file ,my new widget  appeared on the admin side in layout editor.
After i add my widget to page and save it, I don't see it's content on page.

I have added my file contents here. my module name is  `LoginPhonenumber`
and widget name is `hione`.

`content.php`

```
 <?php

    return array(
    array(
   'title' => 'Hi One',
   'description' => 'hi123',
   'category' => 'Login Phonenumber',
   'type' => 'widget',
   'name' => 'login-phonenumber.hione',
   'requirements' => array(
   'no-subject',
   ),
  ),
 ) ?>
```

`Controller.php`

```
<?php

 class LoginPhonenumber_Widget_HioneController extends 
 Engine_Content_Widget_Abstract
 {
  public function indexAction()
  {
   echo "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii";
  } 
 }
?>
```

`index.tpl`

```
<?php echo "Welcome";?>
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem.

Comment: can you show both Controller.php, index.tpl and content.php files?

Comment: @KirkHammett i have edited question with these file contents. Can you please check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to change your module's name: none of core modules uses kind of naming similar to `login-phonenumber`. All modules are named as one single word:

[image]

As you can see, even if module name contains more than one word, they're named as a single word, without dashes. In case if you'll use module with dash inside you'll most probably receive next warning:

`WARN (4): exception 'Engine_Content_Exception' with message 'Widget's module is not enabled or not installed: "login-phonenumber"'`

which allows us to understand that SocialEngine can't identify a module with such name, even if its name in database as `login-phonenumber`.

Comment: if the widget is named with dashes, have any issue? I named my widget with dashes. I got  'missing widget'  in admin side , after i add my widget to page and save it.

Comment: @Agnes widget can be named with dashes, you can see a lot of examples of such naming in core module, for example in module User.